# Give a basis for $\mathrm{Ker}(T)$ and $\mathrm{Im}(T)$ of the linear transformations

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I was given the following problem:

Let $T:\mathbb {R^3} \rightarrow \mathbb {P_2(\mathbb {R})} $ and $G:\mathbb {P_2(\mathbb {R})} \rightarrow \mathbb {R^3}$ Linear transformations such that:

$[
 T]_{B,C} =
 \begin{pmatrix}
  1 & 2 & -1 &  \\
  1 & 0 & -1 & \\ 
  0 & 1 & 1 & \\
 \end{pmatrix}
$

$[
 G]_{C,B} =
 \begin{pmatrix}
  1 & 2 & 2 &  \\
  1 & -1 & 0 & \\ 
  -1 & 1 & 0 & \\
 \end{pmatrix}
$

where $B=\{(1,1,0),(0,1,0),(0,0,1)\}$ and $C=\{1,1+x,1+x^2\}$

a)Give the basis for $KerT$ and $ImT$

b)Give basis for $Ker(G\circ T)$ and $ImT(G\circ T)$

c)give the matrix of $H=3(T\circ G)+I$ with respect to the basis $\{1,x,x^2\}$

Then my doubt is how to find the kernel and image of the linear transformation. The doubt is basically in the part a) of the problem. Having got that, I guess I can solve the other parts.

Comment: Looks like homework..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a) $T$ is invertible. Therefore Kernel is 0  Image the whole thing.

b) Kernel of $G$ are multiples of $(2,2,-3)$.