# Find bases for $\ker T,\text{im}\,T$ with respect to the members of $B$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

> Assume that $V$ is a $4$-dimension vector space and $B=\{e_1,e_2,e_3,e_4\}$ is a basis of $V$.  If $T : V \to V$ is a linear transformation such that the matrix representation of $T$ with respect to $B$ is
> $$
>         \begin{bmatrix}
>         1 & 0 & 2 & 1 \\
>         -1 & 2 & 1 & 3 \\
>         1 & 2 & 5 & 5 \\
>         2 & -2 & 1 & -2 \\
>         \end{bmatrix}
> $$
> Find a basis for $\ker T$, $\text{im}\,T$ with respect to the members of $B$.

---

Note 1 : I'm sorry but I have no idea about this problem... I have never found the basis of kernel and image with the use of matrix representation.

Note 2 : By $e_1$ I mean $(1,0,0,0)$ . You can guess what $e_2,e_3,e_4$ are.

Comment: Do you know how to solve system of linear equations by Gaussian elimination?

Comment: Do you know the definiton of ker $(T)$ and im$(T)$? I am sure there are lot of similar kind of questions on MSE already.

Comment: @ArpitKansal Yes i know the definitions ... no, this kind of question ( finding the basis of kernel and image when matrix representation is given ) is not between the similar questions :) anyway, please help me :)

Comment: @ZoranLoncarevic yes but how is that useful ?

Comment: @Jack would you please answer the question ? you just draw a line ... it's not useful sir :)

Comment: $$\ker(T)=\{ v \in V \mid Tv=0\}=\{\alpha_1 e_1 + \cdots + \alpha_4 e_4 \mid (mat_B T) [\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_4]' = 0 \}$$ and $(mat_B T) [\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_4]' = 0$ is system of linear equations.

Comment: Dear @ArmanMalekzade: Did you really try to find similar questions? ofc by similar i dint mean the exact question.For instance you can see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1675859/how-to-find-the-basis-for-kert-of-the-following-linear-transformation?rq=1) and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/218913/give-a-basis-for-mathrmkert-and-mathrmimt-of-the-linear-transforma?rq=1) and plenty more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you say you don't know how to find kernel and image from matrix representation, but I assume that you could if I gave you explicit formula for $T$?

Then, we have

$$\begin{pmatrix}
        1 & 0 & 2 & 1 \\
        -1 & 2 & 1 & 3 \\
        1 & 2 & 5 & 5 \\
        2 & -2 & 1 & -2 \\
        \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
        x_1 \\
        x_2 \\
        x_3 \\
        x_4 \\
        \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
        x_1 +2x_3 + x_4\\
        -x_1+2x_2+x_3+3x_4 \\
        x_1+2x_2+5x_3+5x_4 \\
        2x_1-2x_2+x_3-2x_4 \\
        \end{pmatrix}$$ or $$T(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4) = (x_1 +2x_3 + x_4,
        -x_1+2x_2+x_3+3x_4,
        x_1+2x_2+5x_3+5x_4,
        2x_1-2x_2+x_3-2x_4)$$

Now, you can easily find all $x$ such that $Tx = 0$ and all $y$ that are of the form $Tx = y$, right?

...

Probably not.

To find the kernel you need to solve linear system $Tx = 0$, and how do you solve linear systems? Well, you write them as matrices. I will leave to you to solve system with extended matrix given as $$\left(\begin{array}{cccc|c}
        1 & 0 & 2 & 1 & 0\\
        -1 & 2 & 1 & 3 & 0\\
        1 & 2 & 5 & 5 & 0\\
        2 & -2 & 1 & -2 & 0\\
        \end{array}\right)$$

And what about the image? Well take a look again at what typical element of $\operatorname{im} T$ looks like:

$$\begin{pmatrix}
        x_1 +2x_3 + x_4\\
        -x_1+2x_2+x_3+3x_4 \\
        x_1+2x_2+5x_3+5x_4 \\
        2x_1-2x_2+x_3-2x_4 \\
        \end{pmatrix}= x_1\begin{pmatrix}
        1 \\
        -1 \\
        1 \\
        2 \\
        \end{pmatrix} + x_2 \begin{pmatrix}
        0\\
        2 \\
        2\\
        -2\\
        \end{pmatrix} + x_3\begin{pmatrix}
        2\\
        1\\
        5\\
        1\\
        \end{pmatrix} + x_4\begin{pmatrix}
        1 \\
        3 \\
        5 \\
        -2 \\
        \end{pmatrix}$$

Thus, $\operatorname{im} T = \operatorname{span}\{(1,-1,1,2),(0,2,2,-2),(2,1,5,1),(1,3,5,-2)\}$. Now, this doesn't need to be base, but it is generating set so you can reduce it to base. Can you finish the task now?

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\img}{\mathrm{im \,}}$> I have no idea about this problem

First of all, you might be interested in Gowers's article about "[fake difficult](https://gowers.wordpress.com/2011/09/23/welcome-to-the-cambridge-mathematical-tripos/)" and also the thread [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/17164/9464).

---

Exercises:

- Write down what is $\img(T)$ *by definition*. (This is the starting point of the problem. One has to know exactly what this is in order to go on.)
- > $\img(T)$ consists of *all* the linear combinations of the columns of $T$.
- Find a basis for $im(T)$. (This is a very standard exercise in linear algebra. Every standard textbook should at least have a related example.)
- > Essentially, you are asked to find a set of linearly independent vectors among the columns of $T$. A systematic way to do it is by Gaussian elimination.
- Write down what is $\ker(T)$.
- Find a basis for $\ker(T)$.

---

> I have never found the basis of kernel and image with the use of matrix representation.

You are making things complicated. Since $V=\mathbb{R}^4$ and $T$ is represented with respect to the standard basis $\{e_1,\cdots,e_4\}$ , one can view $T$ *as* its representing matrix.

Comment: The problem is about $im(T)$ . I can't find it's basis ... even a hint is more useful than the humiliation you made me feel ... what you wrote is not the answer ... its not a good behavior in this website sir

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

For the image of $T$, sort out all linearly independant columns of $T$.
For the kernel of $T$, check which vectors in $V$ map to $0$.